# Add object list to DB context in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-6

Here is one approach where we can add items in database context one by one for save data.

```
  List<AuditTrails> auditLogs= new List<AuditTrails>();

  foreach (AuditTrail a in auditLogs)
  {
      if (a.Operation == CreatedBy)
      {
         if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.NewState))
             context.AuditTrails.Add(a);
      }
      else
         context.AuditTrails.Add(a);
  }
  context.SaveChanges();
```

Is there any way to do without Loop? I am working with Entity Framework 6.
                `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can use the [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.addrange(v=vs.113).aspx) method, but first you have to filter your collection as @ChrisPratt suggests in his answer:

```
var elementsToBeAdded=auditLogs.Where(a => (a.Operation == CreatedBy && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.NewState)) || 
                                            a.Operation != CreatedBy);
context.AuditTrails.AddRange(elementsToBeAdded);
```

If [`AutoDetectChangesEnabled`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.autodetectchangesenabled(v=vs.113).aspx) is set to `true` (which is the default), then `DetectChanges` will be called once before adding any entities and will not be called again. This means that in some situations `AddRange` may perform significantly better than calling `Add` multiple times would do. Note that entities that are already in the context in some other state will have their state set to `Added`. `AddRange` is a no-op for entities that are already in the context in the `Added` state

Comment: Suggested small improvement: `auditLogs.Where(a => !(a.Operation == CreatedBy && string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.NewState));`

Answer (score 3):

Technically, no, but you can, I think, get the gist of what you're looking for via the `ForEach` method of `List`.

```
auditLogs.Where(a =>
    (a.Operation == CreatedBy && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(a.NewState)) || 
    a.Operation != CreatedBy
).ToList().ForEach(a => context.AuditTrails.Add(a));
```